# Linux Mint/Windows 10 Internet Issues

Tags: linux, dual-boot

I installed Linux Mint 18 on a new SSD. I can boot into Windows 10 and use the internet, but booting into LM and trying to use the internet doesn't work. It loads the LM start page but nothing else. It says it's connected but I can't seem to ping anything.

Thanks in advance, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the MTU in the settings with

> sudo ifconfig eno1 mtu 8192

fixed it.

You can also add

> mtu 8192

to /etc/network/interfaces with sudo gedit.

Answer (score 0):

Check the network configuration, does the IP address distributed correctly? If Windows 10 can use the Internet , the network is correct.Try to ping the router address to identify whether the IP address is correct